# Run node app and jar file on boot Raspbian

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, raspbian, boot

I have two files, one that contains a NodeJS server and one file .jar that contains a Java server.
I need to run both of them when my system boots. I'm on Raspbian on RaspberryPi 4.

I created a file called serversBoot which content is:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar server.jar
node webServer.js
```

The Java server starts correctly, but the node one doesn't seem to.
Also I have no idea how to make this script run as soon as my Raspberry boots
I can assure that running in the terminal the same commands I put in the bash script works just fine.
What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
When the commands are put into two different files it works, it doesn't work when put in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start each command as a separate process. In your script `java -jar...` command is blocking the execution of anything else for as long as that process is running.

Try killing the java process to see if `node webServer.js` starts.

To start both, just ask bash to send each process to background:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar server.jar &
node webServer.js &
```

To manage these 2 processes a bit better you should capture their PIDs, so that you know which process to look at. You can get the PIDs like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar server.jar & java_pid=$!
node webServer.js & node_pid=$!
echo $java_pid > java.pid
echo $node_pid > node.pid
```

This way `.pid` files contain the process IDs of the started processes.

See more [info on starting and managing processes from bash scripts here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement)

Comment: Thanks it does work. I only need to run it automatically when the system boots now.